# Sorting of files based on version number in the middle of the file name

Tags: powershell, sorting, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, version-sort

I am new to the power shell. I am trying to sort a list of files which are having version number in the middle of the name.

Here is the list of files :

```
sample-file-1.1.0-patch.zip
sample-file-1.1.1-patch.zip
sample-file-1.1.2-patch.zip
sample-file-1.1.2.1-fix-patch.zip
sample-file-1.1.3-patch.zip
sample-file-1.1.3.1-fix-patch.zip
..
sample-file-1.1.15-patch.zip
sample-file-1.1.15.1-fix-patch.zip
sample-file-1.1.15.2-fix-patch.zip
..
sample-file-2.0.0-patch.zip
sample-file-2.0.1-patch.zip
..
```

I would request you to help me with the sorting logic.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest approach with your sample input is the following, which assumes that the first digit following `-` starts the version number and that it ends with the last digit before a subsequent `-`:

```
Get-ChildItem *.zip | Sort-Object { [version]($_.Name -replace '^[^\d]+-(.*\d)-.*', '$1') }
```

- `$_.Name -replace '^[^\d]+-(.*\d)-.*', '$1'` extracts the version number from each file name as a string.
- `[version]` casts that string to a version-number object ([`System.Version`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))<sup>[1]</sup>
  , which is sortable based on the version-number components.
- Passing the whole expression as a script block `{ ... }` to `Sort-Object` means that sorting is based on the `[version]` instances returned by the script block, evaluated for each input filename.

---

<sup>[1] PSv5.1 introduced a related type, `[System.Management.Automation.SemanticVersion]`, based on [semantic versioning](http://semver.org), which wouldn't work here, however, because it only supports *3* version-number components.</sup>

Comment: @AniSaw: Glad to hear it; my pleasure.